# ERROR: syntax error at or near "entity" LINE 14: FACET entity.name AS 'instanceId'

Tags: newrelic, gcp-cloudsql

I was successfully able to configure newrelic for my cloudsql for postgresql instance. Also, I could see the instance monitoring into newrelic dashboard. However, when I'm running below query on the db instance, I'm getting below error:

```
SELECT 
 instanceId, 
 maxCpu, 
 maxMemoryUtilization, 
 maxTransactionsCount,
 maxDiskUtilization
FROM (
 SELECT 
 max(database.cpu.Utilization) AS maxCpu, 
 max(gcp.cloudsql.database.memory.utilization) AS maxMemoryUtilization,
 max(gcp.cloudsql.database.postgresql.transaction_count) AS maxTransactionsCount,
 max(gcp.cloudsql.database.disk.utilization) AS maxDiskUtilization
 FROM Metric 
 FACET entity.name AS 'instanceId'
 LIMIT MAX
) WHERE instanceId like '%my-db-instance%'
LIMIT MAX
SINCE 2 weeks ago
```

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "entity" LINE 14:  FACET entity.name AS 'instanceId'`

Not sure, why I'm still getting error after successful configuration. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the clause "AS" with the clause "FACET".

Change from:

```
FACET entity.name AS 'instanceId'
```

To:

```
FACET `entity.name`
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your response. I have removed `AS 'instanceId'` , but now I'm getting error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "entity"
LINE 14:  FACET entity.name .

Not sure, what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Try to add single quotes like showed in the  answer (I just edited it).

Comment: Thank you once again for immediate response. Not sure, may be I'm wrong with something else, now I'm getting below error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 14:  FACET `entity.name`

Comment: Is everything ok with the quotes? I ask this because one quote seems missing in your previous message.

Comment: Thanks, quotes seems alright. It's because `` syntax catches differently here. So, it seems to be missing quote here